# Difference between arg unpacking in the following

Tags: python, language-lawyer

What would be the difference between the following two statements:

```
>>> from_vargs_1 = lambda *x: list(x)
>>> from_vargs_2 = lambda *x: x
```

In other words, with the explicit `list` or without it. Does the equality `tuple(from_vargs_1(...)) == from_vargs_2(...)` always hold?

Comment: I don't understand what possibilities you're worried about here, or why you find it unsatisfactory or insufficient evidence to just try the code. I added the [language-lawyer] tag because I think that's the kind of question you're trying to ask, but really this is more straightforward than you expect.

Comment: Given that you understand `x` is a tuple, the question doesn't seem to be about argument unpacking so much as *"is it always true that for a tuple `x`, `tuple(list(x)) == x`?"* In that case the answer is even more clearly "yes, of course". I say this because both lambdas take their arguments the same way, so there can't be any difference caused by the argument unpacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been quicker to try it.

```
from_vargs1 = lambda *x: list(x)
from_vargs2 = lambda *x: x
x = from_vargs1( 1, 2, 3 )
y = from_vargs2( 1, 2, 3 )
print( x )
print( y )
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
(1, 2, 3)
```

Yes, when you use `*x`, positional arguments to a function are passed as a tuple.

Comment: @Time -- thanks for the answer. Yes, I did try, and got something like this: `>>> tuple(from_vargs_1(*x))==from_vargs_2(*x)` `True`. But was looking for something a bit more authoritative than just "I tried it one time and it gave me the same thing."

Comment: That's a fair enough complaint.  Here's a page from the Python documentation.  About 2/3 of the way down, it says that the `*x` notation is initialized to a tuple containing the extra parameters.  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions